# wordpress not all javsscripts loaded

Tags: wordpress

after akeeba backup wordpress site on another domain, not all javasctipts loaded. On main domain all scripts loaded properly.For example there are such code in ignitiondeck plugin.

```
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'idf_lightbox');
  add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'idf_lightbox');

  function idf_lightbox() {
   if (function_exists('get_plugin_data')) {
       $idf_data = get_plugin_data(__FILE__);
   }
   wp_register_script('idf', plugins_url('js/idf.js', __FILE__));
   wp_register_style('magnific', plugins_url('lib/magnific/magnific.css', __FILE__));
   wp_register_script('magnific', plugins_url('lib/magnific/magnific.js', __FILE__));
   wp_register_script('idf-admin-media', plugins_url('/js/idf-admin-media.js', __FILE__));
   wp_register_style('idf', plugins_url('css/idf.css', __FILE__));
   wp_register_script('idf-stock-browser', plugins_url('js/idf-stock-browser.js', __FILE__));

   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

   $checkout_url = '';
   $platform = idf_platform();
   if ($platform == 'wc' && !is_admin()) {
       if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
           global $woocommerce;
           $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
       }
   }
   else if ($platform == 'edd' && class_exists('Easy_Digital_Downloads') && !is_admin()) {
       $checkout_url = edd_get_checkout_uri();
   }
   wp_enqueue_style('magnific');
   wp_enqueue_style('idf');
   wp_enqueue_script('idf');
   wp_enqueue_script('magnific');
   if ($platform == 'legacy' || $platform == 'wc') {
       wp_register_script('idflegacy-js', plugins_url('js/idf-legacy.js', __FILE__));
       wp_enqueue_script('idflegacy-js');
   }
   wp_localize_script('idf', 'idf_platform', $platform);
   // Let's set the ajax url
   $idf_ajaxurl = site_url('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php');
   wp_localize_script('idf', 'idf_siteurl', site_url());
   wp_localize_script('idf', 'idf_ajaxurl', $idf_ajaxurl);
   wp_localize_script('idf', 'idf_logged_in', (is_user_logged_in() ? '1' : '0'));
   if (isset($checkout_url)) {
       wp_localize_script('idf', 'idf_checkout_url', $checkout_url);
   }
   if (isset($idf_data['Version'])) {
       wp_localize_script('idf', 'idf_version', $idf_data['Version']);
   }
   wp_enqueue_script('idf-stock-browser');
  }
```

In chrome network there are

- jquery.js
- idf.js
- idf-stock-browser

But there are no

- magnific.js

All css loaded properly. I have tried change folder rights for 755 and 777 but no result. Script is accessible by direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
Problem was in `require_once` not existed path in another plugn.
Strange, but `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` doesn't show the error.